# Administrator can run a application but produces error while a administrator previllaged user can run without error

Tags: user-accounts, windows-server-2003, administrator, privileges, ms-sql

I have an application which can run as admin prevailed user without error but while administrator runs it it produces error. `The input string was not in correct format`-application error. 
I tried to figure it out but not possible, since most of the people are looking for admin privilege to run it, me looking why can't a admin run the program without errors?
The program is related to `mssql-2008 r2`. The SQL log-in settings are same for both the users.

Comment: I would assume the program has to be run as administrator. Can you test by right clicking the application, properties and under compatibility check the Run as Administrator. I know this isn't answering you but I'm curious if it fixes it.

Comment: @DaveRook      Thanks for the response. Sorry I did not mention that I am logged in as administrator and running it as administrator, it is a windows server 2003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, administrator and regular user have different regional settings.
For example, user has numbers formatted as "1,234.56" and admin as "1 234,56".

You may check this by running powershell as admin and user and checking for differences in output of:

> (123456).ToString("N")
>
> [DateTime]::Now

Comment: Thanks a lot, It seems you are right, yet to test, I will get as soon as I test it.